# XAML - Static resource not set

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have 2 styles in static resources. First ( with name `LabelFont` `SetterProperty="FontSize"`)

```
<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments:"x:Double" Phone="15", Tablet "30"/>.
```

Second is for setting `Margin` with `OnPlatform` and is `BasedOn="LabelFont"` with name `MarginLabel` and `SetterProperty="Margin"`:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
   <On Platform="Android" Value="20,0,0,0" />
</OnPlatform>
```

(Sorry I dont have whole code now, I can post later if its necessary...)
When I define a Label, where I use Style="{StaticResources MarginLabel}" the font is set, but not Margin. No error.
Can anybody help me where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two styles,you could combine them in one：

```
<Style x:Key="MarginLabel" TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="FontSize">
          <Setter.Value>
              <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                  <OnIdiom.Phone>15</OnIdiom.Phone>
                  <OnIdiom.Tablet>30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
              </OnIdiom>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Margin">
          <Setter.Value>
              <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                  <On Platform="Android" Value="20,0,0,0" />
              </OnPlatform>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
</Style>
```

then use like:

```
<Label Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource MarginLabel}"></Label>
```